# how to code c++ via ssh with Vim or Vi?

Tags: ssh, c++, compiler, cloud

Would I have to rent and configure a server or something? I'm sort of new to unix, but when 
I was in school I had this nifty setup where I could ssh from any terminal in linux or mac or putty in windows and point it to an address like

```
ssh pc7.cs.nameofschool.edu
```

then I would be taken to my own directory in their cloud where I could code and save files and make directories. it was like my personal console that I could access from anywhere. they had redhat installed as i recall and they had access to gcc as well as g++ compilers which was awesome! How do I do this now that I am out of school and they deleted my files! I'd rather not spend any money on it but if it weren't too outrageous I would consider it. Thanks! I'm not too advanced a programmer but I am sort of trying to get back into it and it would be nice to be able to access an IDE/compiler from anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to delete your question because it's hard to understand what you're asking. Do you need access to a server accessible over the Internet and that'd be running Linux? If that's the case, that question is really off-topic on this website.

Comment: wow why you so mean man im new to this. After looking at a couple of answers I guess the service I am seeking is a shell provider service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try various free Unix shell providers. SDF, Blinkenshell or Anapnea come to mind. They do offer build tools, and vim.

Answer (score 1):

Never do this, use a remote repository instead, i.e git.

But if you insist, here's two working solution,

1. Use scp protocol within VIM, i.e `gvim scp://konimi@vim.org//var/www/html/tips/add_tip.php`
2. Mount remote directory through SSH protocol, i.e `sshfs`, that way you can edit it locally, and you open another shell to execute make.

Comment: Er. I don't think he's asking how to edit files remotely; he's literally looking for a shell provider since he can't use his school's anymore